# Does a Beta fit have to match the height of my histogram

Tags: beta-distribution, histogram

I used the `ebb` package in `R` to fit a beta to a histogram of data.

[image]

The fit of the beta distribution is the line at the bottom in red.

Though the shape seems reasonable the height is off. What is the explaination for this? Is there a way I can change the scale of my y-axis or does this infer a poor fit?

Also, here is a graph of just the beta function.

[image]

Edit: Thanks for the help everyone! It came down to everyones comments and reading some [docs](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html) on histogram ("Computed Variables"). I found that I needed`geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),bins = 30)`. Here is the final plot.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should scale your data so that its area is 1?

Comment: The normalized height of the highest interval (assuming equal width bins) does not have to match the height of the beta density for it to be a good fit.

Comment: The area of an ordinary frequency histogram is $n$, while the area of a density is $1$. Usually you would rescale the histogram to unit area (trivial with `hist` in R)

Comment: Using ggplot `geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),bins = 30)` did the trick for me.

Comment: Alex, instead of editing your **question** to include the answer, you should create and accept an **answer** using the material from your edit.